# enabling flags on an apt-get installed package (libnetcdf-dev)

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, netcdf, compiler-flags, opendap

Hopefully this is a really easy question, but I am having trouble working it out - I am installing a program which requires netcdf version 4 or later with DAP enabled. I already have libnetcdf-dev installed via apt-get. How can I check whether DAP is enabled, and if it isn't then enable it? The literature I can find seems to suggest using a simple --enable-dap flag during ./config if installing longhand, but how do you do this if you have installed via apt-get?

(I have ubuntu amd64)

Many thanks for your help!
Bex

Comment: AFAIK You can't you need to check if libnetcdf was compiled with --enable-dap. Otherwise you need to download libnetcdf and build it yourself. `apt-get` installs binaries and `*-dev` are development headers of those packages. You could do `apt-get source libnetcdf` and see default flags inside `debain/rules`

Comment: Thanks @sagarchalise. I was afraid of that :S Longhand compiling it is. But if anyone knows better than either of us, do post!

Comment: I donot think building would be an issue in ubuntu. Just  do `apt-get build-dep libnetcdf` and proceed. But you may check if it is enabled by default as well.